# why does assigning a reference to a static class variable break inheritance of such variable?

Tags: php, inheritance, reference, static

I don't understand why, in the code below, $my_foo and $my_bar are correctly inherited by the child class, but if I change $my_foo by assigning a reference to $my_var, the child class still sees the original value..

```
  <?php
    class Foo
    {
        public static $my_foo = 'foo';
        public static $my_bar = 'bar';

        public static function break_inheritance() {
            self::$my_bar = &self::$my_foo;
        }

        public static function foo_print_vars() {
            print self::$my_foo." ";
            print self::$my_bar."\n";
        }
    }

    class Bar extends Foo
    {
        public static function bar_print_vars() {
            print self::$my_foo." ";
            print self::$my_bar."\n";
        }
    }


    Bar::bar_print_vars(); // OUTPUTS foo bar
    Foo::break_inheritance(); 
    Foo::foo_print_vars(); // OUTPUTS foo foo
    Bar::bar_print_vars(); // OUTPUTS foo bar
```

EDIT: this is a similar question: [do extended classes inherit static var values (PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059525) but mine is more focused on inheritance and references.

EDIT2: please note that the point of this question is not about late static binding, but it's why, since $my_foo and $my_bar are inherited, changing them in Foo doesn't affect them when accessed in Bar. And this **only happens with references**. In fact if we change:

```
 public static function break_inheritance() {
            self::$my_bar = self::$my_foo; // removed reference in assignment
        }
```

the behavior totally changes and the last Bar::bar_print_vars(); // OUTPUTS foo foo

Comment: possible duplicate of [do extended classes inherit static var values (PHP)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059525/do-extended-classes-inherit-static-var-values-php)

Comment: Hi @scrowler, I had seen such question and although such question is more generic (user only asks about inheritance of static properties), the answer considers my case as an example. However, I didn't find a clear explanation on what causes this behavior with references, and I decided to ask a question expressly about it.

Answer (score 0):

Foo is a different class than Bar. Try calling `Bar::break_inheritance();` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Think about static properties of a class as global variables with fancy names.

```
class Foo
{
    public static $my_foo = 'foo';
    public static $my_bar = 'bar';
    // ...
}
```

The code above declares two static properties of class `Foo` whose full names are `Foo::$my_foo` and `Foo::$my_bar`.

By extending `Foo`, class `Bar` produces two more static properties named `Bar::$my_foo` and `Bar::$my_bar`.

The code:

```
class Foo
{
    public static function break_inheritance() {
        self::$my_bar = &self::$my_foo;
    }
}
Foo::break_inheritance();
```

modifies `Foo::$my_bar`. It does not affect `Bar::$my_bar`.

If you call it as:

```
Bar::break_inheritance();
```

it still changes `Foo::$my_bar` and does not affect `Bar::$my_bar`.

A reference that uses `self::` is bound on compilation to the property of the class where it is used. It is the same as you write `Foo::$my_bar = &Foo::$my_foo;`. No matter how you call the method `break_inheritance()`, it will always modify `Foo::$my_bar`.

If you want to use method `break_inheritance()` to change `Bar::$my_bar` you have to change it to use `static::` instead of `self::`:

```
class Foo
{
    public static function break_inheritance() {
        static::$my_bar = &static::$my_foo;
    }
}
Foo::break_inheritance();         // Changes `Foo::$my_bar`
Bar::break_inheritance();         // Changes `Bar::$my_bar`
```

This is called [`late static binding`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) and was introduced in [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php).

Late static binding (`static::`) works for class properties and methods the same way `$this->` works for regular properties and methods. It uses the property or the method defined in the class where you use it (in the child class), if any, and not the property or method inherited from the parent class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will focus on the first part, since self and static are quite clear to me, while what wasn't clear was exactly why modifying static variables in the parent class (inside break_inheritance) would not affect the inherited versions. And most important, **why this only happens with references**, because if, for example, break_inheritance() is changed to self::$my_bar = self:$my_foo , well, it doesn't "break inheritance" any longer.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the new feature introduced in PHP version 5.3.0 called [Late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

`Late static binding` comes from the fact that static:: will not be resolved using the class where the method is defined but it will rather be computed using runtime information.