# Assigning static properties by reference behaves differently between PHP5 and PHP7

Tags: php, php-7, late-static-binding

After upgrading from PHP 5 to PHP 7, the following code is producing different results:

```
abstract class TheParent {
    public static $prop;

    public function __construct( $val ) {
        static::set_prop($val);
    }

    public static function set_prop( $val ) {
        $ref_reset = $val;
        static::$prop =& $ref_reset;
    }
}

class Child extends TheParent {
    // public static $prop;     //<-- not declared on purpose
}

class Child2 extends TheParent {
    // public static $prop;     //<-- not declared on purpose
}

$c  = new Child('do');
$c2 = new Child2('re');

echo 'Child: ' . Child::$prop . '<br>';
echo 'Child2: ' . Child2::$prop . '<br>';
echo 'TheParent: ' . TheParent::$prop;
```

In PHP5:

```
Child: do
Child2: re
TheParent:
```

In PHP7:

```
Child: re
Child2: re
TheParent: re
```

My desired output is the PHP5 output, as I want to be able to reference a single property name in all classes that extend the base (parent) class, but I do not want to redeclare that property or the method that sets it in every single child class (mainly to avoid the maintenance overhead of adding the same property/method to dozens of classes).

It seems the magic in PHP5 was in the assignment by reference (after much hunting on SO, [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577187/php-5-3-late-static-binding-doesnt-work-for-properties-when-defined-in-parent) [answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059525/do-extended-classes-inherit-static-var-values-php) have mentioned that setting by reference "breaks" the "reference set", which allows the properties in each child class to hold separate values). I found this to be a pretty elegant solution in PHP5.

Is there any way to achieve the same result with the same or similar code in PHP7?

### Workaround:

It looks like this is the result of a breaking change between PHP 7.2 and 7.3 and probably doesn't have a similarly elegant two-liner alternative. After refactoring my code, I found this slightly more verbose workaround to be effective (and meeting my main goal of not having to re-declare properties in sub-classes):

```
abstract class TheParent {
    public static $props = [];

    public function __construct( $val ) {
        static::set_prop($val);
    }

    public static function set_prop( $val ) {
        self::$props[static::class] = $val;
    }

    public static function get_prop() {
        if( isset(self::$props[static::class]) )
            return self::$props[static::class];
    }
}

class Child extends TheParent {
    // public static $prop;        //<-- not declared on purpose
}

class Child2 extends TheParent {
    // public static $prop;        //<-- not declared on purpose
}

$c  = new Child('do');
$c2 = new Child2('re');

echo 'Child: ' . Child::get_prop(). '<br>';     // 'do' in PHP 7.3
echo 'Child2: ' . Child2::get_prop() . '<br>';  // 're' in PHP 7.3
echo 'TheParent: ' . TheParent::get_prop();     // ''   in PHP 7.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was changed in PHP 7.2 => 7.3

> Static Properties no longer separated by Reference Assignment
>
> In PHP, static properties are shared between inheriting classes, unless
> the static property is explicitly overridden in a child class.
> However, due to an implementation artifact it was possible to separate
> the static properties by assigning a reference. This loophole has been
> fixed.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame this "loophole" was considered in need of "fixing." I wonder if there's a similarly concise way to achieve the same outcome in PHP7?

Comment: I haven't found any other then going through all of the subclasses and declare the "extended" static property there as well. Let me know if you can thing of a better approach

Comment: My workaround was to add a static array property to the base class and add the names of the subclasses to the array that I want to mark as "set." Not quite as elegant, but gets the job done without having to re-declare properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is something wrong with your local environment.

You can check your code with **[php-sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86cdb7055b77d865d7dbbbe185c19e4bd96182ad)**.

I check it, and for **php5** and **php7** result is the same.

Comment: result will change in PHP 7.3